# How can one reliably prevent pedestrian access to a parking garage, but allow vehicular access?

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, design, building-design, infrastructure

Consider a typical private parking garage for a condominium or apartment building.

There is currently a typical garage gate that opens and closes (slowly) to allow vehicles to pass safely through the gate.

What is the optimal method for preventing access into this garage by pedestrians/foot traffic, but ensuring the same safe entry/exit for vehicles?

The goal is to make sure people cannot enter/exit through the same gate that vehicles may enter/exit.

Practically implementable solutions only, please.  Cost need not be a factor.

Comment: Since a human is smaller than a car, then obviously you can't *prevent* access. Of course you can make *unauthorized* access more difficult by conventional methods like locks and keys, CCTV monitors, etc.

Comment: @alephzero: I appreciate that answer, although, respectfully, I'm not convinced that access cannot be prevented.  Someone else to whom I posed this question referred to an automatic car wash; while this is not access control in and of itself, it makes the process of pedestrian entry/exit MUCH more difficult than vehicular entry/exit.

Thanks!

Comment: How will pedestrians be prevented from entering via the same gate at the same time as a vehicle is passing through the entrance or immediately before or after the vehicle passes through?

Comment: If cost isn't a factor, just hire an attendant/armed guard.

Comment: You'd need the equivalent of an ainsible so that only non-organic outer-shell objects can pass, and even then a person in an Iron Man suit could get by.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Presumably the driver and any legitimate passengers need to pass through the door. Therefore anybody else can do the same simply by hijacking the car.

Comment: So pedestrian access is OK, just not through the same gate as the vehicles?

Comment: Hot water curtain!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Dual gates, with the outer one always closing before the inner one opens.

For extra security, a computer vision system could check that no people are present in the intermediate space before opening the inner gate.

Comment: Nice.  Perhaps the most practical answer yet.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure sensor that triggers alarm if something less than 1 ton but more than 10kg enters the garage.

Electrify the floor, anyone walking in will be fried without a Faraday's cage protection.

Fill whole garage with carbon monoxide fumes after entering. Suck out the fumes after 5min.

Comment: +1.  I could only come up with similarly aggressive solutions to actually make sure people didn't get in.  If safety is an issue you would want to relax the requirements on people sneaking in.

Comment: Unfortunately rubber-soled shoes will negate the second idea. Replace w/ high-voltage wires dangling from the ceiling, but which retract when the incoming object is heavy enough to trigger those pressure sensors.

Comment: @Giant: I'm quite partial in particular to option 2; alas, I'm afraid Carl Witthoft is spot on - rubber soles doth an intruder enable.

Comment: Also, @JMac, I am interested in any ideas, regardless of the perceived level of aggression.  Let 'em rip.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a passive solution like a Cattle Grid for people that would heavily discourage anyone from trying to walk on it.

But then you might have to deal with the idiots that might get stuck and/or break they legs trying to cross one.

Another passive solution is a ditch with about 6 inches of water, because I don't think anyone would want to soak their shoes and pants trying to use the car entrance.

Comment: Thanks for these great ideas.  Passive solutions are nice because they are generally cheaper and less maintenance (yes, I know I said cost is not a factor, but that was meant primarily to spark more creative responses).  I hadn't even heard of a cattle grid before - great idea, but as you said, we will then have to deal with the idiots that will get stuck and/or break legs trying to cross it, who will then, of course, invariably sue.  Great ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Since cost is not an issue how about an armed guard. Not every problem is an engineering problem.